# how to change music tonality in runtime?

Tags: audio

On windows usualy for karaoke purpose some audio cards provide possibility to change tonality on fly, is it possible under Mac ?

Is ther any additional software which can do it ? or maybe terminal command ?

Comment: Just saw this post http://evolver.fm/2013/03/19/how-to-equalize-mac-for-itunes-spotify-everything-else/ and thought of your question... Haven't tried this myself but it looks like you might get close with Sunflower and AU Lab.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Capo](http://supermegaultragroovy.com/products/Capo/).
From their Website:

> Pitch Adjustment
>
> Capo lets you adjust the pitch of your songs—so you can change their
>   key or fine tune them to match your instrument.

Comment: It means that I can do it only for particular song, which will play in that app. But I would like to have it in system wide area

Comment: yeah with capo you can only adjust it for the currently loaded song.

Comment: but I'm looking something system wide solution :(